# how to return the average of a sql time field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql database with a time field.

The runtime time field contains `02:06:24, 00:01:12` etc...

I am trying to return the average of this field in the HH:MM:SS format using;

```
SELECT AVG( runtime )
FROM `result`
```

This returns `8312.2342729307` which I thought was the average in seconds however when converted into minutes this is incorrect.

I am able to return the MIN and MAX runtimes in the correct format however cannot get the AVG, how do i do this?

Failing that is there anyway to select the middle element to use as a median average?

Comment: It is unclear which databases you are using: Only MySQL? Or also another?

Comment: Im not sure to be honest, its hosted on http://www.numyspace.co.uk/phpmyadmin

Comment: What do you think the average of two o'clock and five o'clock should be? What should the *sum* of two o'clock and five o'clock be?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' - Question says "runtime time" so it's not two o'clock. It's just an amount of seconds expressed as H:M:S

Comment: In standard SQL, the amount of seconds is a different datatype than a time of day. It's called an interval. There are good reasons for the two different data types, and you need to tread carefully on a platform that doesn't support SQL intervals.

Answer (score 3):

So, by way of illustration...

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC('02:06:24')+TIME_TO_SEC('00:01:12'))/2) x;
+----------+
| x        |
+----------+
| 01:03:48 |
+----------+
```

Comment: SELECT SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC('22:06:24')+TIME_TO_SEC('00:01:12'))/2) x;

gives me 11:03:48.0000... Which is wrong result. Correct result should be 23:XX ...

Comment: @ApoorvaShah Your's is a different problem from the one originally asked. Also XX isn't a valid time.

Comment: yes xx means some second... i have not calculated exact average.

Comment: i do not know i have not down vote. Some one else may done. Its may be co incidence i comment and you get down vote.

Comment: Sorry our team is searching same answer with my account. I just see down vote from my account. I am doing up vote now. Sorry once again.

Comment: please edit answer anything space then only i can up vote.

Comment: @ApoorvaShah Incidentally, your latest question is woefully inadequate. Please delete it, and see the help pages about how to ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the AVG() function against a DATETIME/TIME

I am casting DATETIME to DECIMAL( 18, 6 ) which appears to yield a reasonably (+- few milliseconds) precise result.

```
SELECT cast(CAST( AVG( CAST( runtime AS DECIMAL( 18, 6 ) ) ) AS DATETIME ) as time)
FROM dbo.result;
```

Comment: Its returning a row however this is NULL

Comment: Quick testing suggests that `AVG()` treats `01:30:00` as `13000`, even in strict mode :-? If someone can find the manual page that explains that he should post it here.